# Address boundary error caused by vector for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am trying to print out a board for a game that I am programming. Here is my code for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<char> column1 = { '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'};
vector<char> column2 = column1;
vector<char> column3 = column1;
vector<char> column4 = column1;
vector<char> column5 = column1;
vector<char> column6 = column1;
vector<char> column7 = column1;

vector<vector<char>> all_columns = {
    column1, 
    column2, 
    column3, 
    column4, 
    column5, 
    column6, 
    column7
};

void print_board() {
    cout << "| ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++i)
        {
            cout << all_columns[i][j]
                 << " ";
        }
    cout << "|\n";
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    print_board();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a "SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)" and I can't seem to see the problem with my rotting brain, what am I missing here?

Comment: Whoa, that's quite a waste of space. I hope you know that you can initialize each "column" of `all_columns` without an extra variable.

Comment: [tag:status-norepro].

Comment: Look at your inner loop.

Comment: @Incomputable ah. i see, gosh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by a typo in inner loop. To avoid it, use range loops:

```
for (const auto& row: board)
{
    for (auto cell: row)
    {
        //do something here
    }
 }
```

Usually there is standard algorithm though, try to look for it first.